# How to display child menus from the main menu on Drupal?

Tags: javascript, drupal, menu, navigation, nav

I have the Olivero theme on Drupal 9 (it's the default theme) :

https://tugboat-aqrmztryfqsezpvnghut1cszck2wwasr.tugboatqa.com/

When I reduce the window in width, the navigation switches to mobile novigation.

Here is the HTML code when the main menu is collapsed :

```
<nav id="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu" class="primary-nav block block-menu navigation menu--main" aria-labelledby="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu-menu" role="navigation">  
  <ul class="menu primary-nav__menu primary-nav__menu--level-1" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu--level-1" data-once="olivero-automatic-mobile-nav">
    <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-1 primary-nav__menu-item--has-children" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/on-se-deconfine" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-1 primary-nav__menu-link--has-children" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-link-has-children" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/15">            <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-1">On se déconfine</span>
      </a>
      <button class="primary-nav__button-toggle" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-submenu-toggle-button" aria-controls="primary-menu-item-12" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="visually-hidden">sous-navigation On se déconfine</span>
        <span class="icon--menu-toggle"></span>
      </button>                
      <span data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-" class="primary-nav__menu-"></span>
      <ul class="menu primary-nav__menu primary-nav__menu--level-2" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu--level-2" id="primary-menu-item-12">
        <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">                  
          <a href="/points-dinterets" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/13">            <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Points d'intérêts</span>
          </a>   
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67dR7.png)

Here is the HTML code when the main menu is unfolded :

```
<nav id="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu" class="primary-nav block block-menu navigation menu--main" aria-labelledby="block-subtheme-olivero-main-menu-menu" role="navigation">  
  <ul class="menu primary-nav__menu primary-nav__menu--level-1" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu--level-1" data-once="olivero-automatic-mobile-nav">
    <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-1 primary-nav__menu-item--has-children" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/on-se-deconfine" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-1 primary-nav__menu-link--has-children" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-link-has-children" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/15">            <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-1">On se déconfine</span>
      </a>
      <button class="primary-nav__button-toggle" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-submenu-toggle-button" aria-controls="primary-menu-item-12" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="visually-hidden">sous-navigation On se déconfine</span>
        <span class="icon--menu-toggle"></span>
      </button>                
      <span data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu-" class="primary-nav__menu- is-active-menu-parent"></span>
      <ul class="menu primary-nav__menu primary-nav__menu--level-2 is-active-menu-parent" data-drupal-selector="primary-nav-menu--level-2" id="primary-menu-item-12">
        <li class="primary-nav__menu-item primary-nav__menu-item--link primary-nav__menu-item--level-2">                  
          <a href="/points-dinterets" class="primary-nav__menu-link primary-nav__menu-link--link primary-nav__menu-link--level-2" data-drupal-link-system-path="taxonomy/term/13">            <span class="primary-nav__menu-link-inner primary-nav__menu-link-inner--level-2">Points d'intérêts</span>
          </a>   
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZlWO.png)

What should I add in the script.js file of my subtheme, so that the main menu displays the child menus on mobile (only when nivigation is in mobile mode) ?

Maybe you need to create a custom module to do this.

In Drupal's main menu configuration, the "Show unfolded" option has no effect.

I knew how to do it on Bootstrap because there is documentation, but on Olivero I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Please add the code as text and not as image, this makes it much easier to read!

Comment: @cloned There is a lot of code. I updated my question tried to present it properly.